# Shiny: creating and understanding a simple app

Tags: r, shiny

I know some R and now would like to create a first simple app. Here is the dataframe I have:

> x

```
            Var1 Freq MotherAlive Deaths
1  -0.3574849239  128           1     61
2  -0.3426329835  125           2    111
3  -0.2279137719  110           2     96
4  -0.2038604979   81           1     63
5  -0.2004248235   94           2    119
6  -0.1866284306  153           2    128
7  -0.1762490299  124           1    109
8  -0.1736353449   87           2     91
9  -0.1624588718   51           2    134
10 -0.1503921713   88           1    105
11 -0.1501143228  151           1    140
12 -0.1492320254  128           2    126
13 -0.1484292603   97           2     78
14 -0.1431025682  116           2    105
15 -0.1339971398   52           1    133
16 -0.1336509151   43           1    106
17 -0.1329288171   98           1    122
18 -0.1174806726  104           2    119
19 -0.1170459477  111           1    139
20 -0.1063311927  140           2    106
21 -0.1063101037  118           1    138
22 -0.1052133391   64           2    125
23 -0.1009333742   78           1     85
24 -0.0932270424  112           2    140
25 -0.0765785108   59           1     96
26 -0.0748168224   72           1    110
27 -0.0725537833   70           2     91
28 -0.0702932290  111           2     63
29 -0.0689926554   51           2     77
30 -0.0607975570  111           1    125
31 -0.0583357003  138           2     68
32 -0.0535012169   53           1     75
33 -0.0505603465   96           2     67
34 -0.0392230996  105           1     67
35 -0.0373462508   99           1     65
36 -0.0355835995   75           2    128
37 -0.0316295745   55           1     92
38 -0.0313050685  115           1    120
39 -0.0241317373   62           2    124
40 -0.0214325431   89           2    134
41 -0.0210084740   79           2    104
42 -0.0179134498   53           2    104
43 -0.0117510238  129           1    100
44 -0.0086331499   75           1     83
45  0.0008978007   57           2     79
46  0.0076018541   60           1    127
47  0.0124470800   45           2     96
48  0.0192847770   68           2    110
49  0.0195626326   84           1     76
50  0.0277658621   93           2     78
51  0.0324838136   66           2     93
52  0.0427433106  109           2    110
53  0.0542162036   61           2     73
54  0.0617228677  104           1    136
55  0.0732288400  113           2     73
56  0.0805244157   52           1     61
57  0.0933868304  141           1     68
58  0.0962572600   47           1    111
59  0.0992007270   98           1     74
60  0.1126662494  137           1     67
61  0.1175718095   91           2     65
62  0.1193833698   76           2    110
63  0.1321158054   56           1    122
64  0.1346171097  142           1    136
65  0.1461559695   80           2     60
66  0.1551994333  160           1     76
67  0.1645405730  147           1     67
68  0.1672903379  124           1     71
69  0.1680942594  108           2     87
70  0.1805845470   67           2     63
71  0.1899103023   85           1     78
72  0.1988461353  150           2     97
73  0.2034001399   64           2    129
74  0.2182855107   90           1     94
75  0.2200093156  101           1    125
76  0.3053271995  104           2    112
77  0.3337327069   72           2    124
78  0.3668031727  100           1     75
79  0.4302071402  151           2     69
```

what I want is rather simple I suppose: I want two sliders, Deviation from Rye_Prices-Cycle and MotherAlive (they are produced and work so far) and I want them to display the number of deaths, births or both according to their values. But there are, apparently some little conceptual think I do not really understand. I have written the following:

```
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {
  options(device.ask.default = FALSE)

  ui <- fluidPage(    
    titlePanel("Events"),
    sidebarLayout(      
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("Var1", "Deviation from Rye_Prices-Cycle", min = -0.5, max = 0.5, value = 0),
        sliderInput("MotherAlive", "MotherAlive", min = 1, max = 2, value = 1)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("EventPlot")  
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$EventPlot <- renderPlot({
      plot(x[,input$Var1], 
              main=input$Var1,
              ylab="Freq",
              xlab="Deaths")
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Again, I think there are some basic conception I do not understand. Could somebody help a little in explaining what I should do?

Thank you guys.

Kind regards:
Benjamin

Comment: in the former formulation of the Question there was a "Hi guys" too... I forgot it this time ;)

Comment: The only error is on the server side : ` Error in plot: object 'x' not found`. You just didn't initialize your data frame `x` in your app and hence it cannot be plotted. What is `x` ?

Comment: Thank you Antoine. Would you have any suggestions on how to do this best?

Comment: What do your sliders aim to do ? And what actual plot you'd like to draw depending on these values ?

Comment: Because now it is showing the graph but not reacting to changes: if 
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$EventPlot <- renderPlot({
      plot(x$Deaths, breaks = input$Var1, 
              main=input$Freq,
              ylab="Freq",
              xlab="Deaths")
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}

Comment: I want to so if there are more births or death if the price increases and if there are more births or death if there is a mother alive or not. so: how do the events change if a) there is a price increase or b) the mother died (with Var1 being the prices and Freq the number of births)

Comment: so there is something wrong then in the concept itself probably? does it make sense to show such a plot with this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to use Shiny for this kind of plot in my opinion. For what reasons would you want to use Shiny and what would be the actual use of the two sliders you mention ? Apart from subsetting your data (e.g. with `checkboxInput()` to plot when `MotherAlive == 1` or `2`), I don't see anything else that is relevant to do with Shiny.

I will try to display all the information contained in your data `x` with only one plot. I am using the `ggplot2` infrastructure :

```
ggplot(x) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Deaths, y = Freq, size = Var1, colour = as.factor(MotherAlive))) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Deaths, y = Freq, colour = as.factor(MotherAlive))) + 
  labs(col = "MotherAlive") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

This is the *Frequency* in function of the number of *Deaths*, for each value of *MotherAlive* (`1` or `2`, controlled with the `colour` argument) and where the `size` of the points indicate the value of *Rye_Prices-Cycle* (named `Var1` in your dataset).

What else would you want from Shiny ?

Comment: Thanks Antoine. I agree with you, your graph does the job. My idea is just that I want to learn shiny. So I created this data frame and then tried to plot something. I will try your suggestion with the checkbox and come up with something more thoughtful.

Comment: There are lots of better ways to learn Shiny, with dedicated datasets for this ! Check out for example this [list of examples](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) made by Rstudio, among others.  All these examples can be reproduced.